# how to web scrape a nested table from html with python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

i want to scrape a web nested table with python selenium. The table format has 4 columns x 10 rows. The 4th column has an inner cell containing 6 spans storing 6 images in each row.

My problem is i can only scrape the first 3 columns but cannot show the 4th column data with 6 image src in correct row order.

```
row = mstable.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultMainTable"]/div/div')
column = mstable.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultMainTable"]/div/div[1]/div')
column_4th = mstable.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultMainTable"]/div/div/div[4]')
innercell_column_4th = mstable.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultMainTable"]/div/div/div[4]/span[1]/img')


span_1 = mstable.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultMainTable"]/div/div/div/span[1]/img')
span_2 = mstable.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultMainTable"]/div/div/div/span[2]/img')

for new_span_1 in span_1:
    span_1_img = (new_span_1.get_attribute('src'))

for new_span_2 in span_2:
    span_2_img = (new_span_2.get_attribute('src'))

for new_row in row:
    print ((new_row.text), (span_1_img), (span_2_img))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use selenium along with BeautifulSoup . In the BeautifulSoup class when it ask about page source use the selenium function called selenium.page_source instead of requests module which cant recognise javascript.

Comment: i could load the page source. My problem is i dont know how to loop through and display the inner cell image src.

Comment: just inspect the webpage element

Comment: then i moved to beautiful soup.it is far better